# What does "67% above average engagement rate" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I saw an advertisement for the new release of Xbox (The title is "The Birth of Gaming Tourism").
And there is a phrase that read "67% above average engagement rate" to explain how effective the campaign was in terms of marketing, I guess.

But I cannot figure out what that means exactly.
Does that mean the average engagement rate is over 67%?
Or the above engagement rate is 67%?

Please help me understand the meaning.
It would be very helpful to me.
Thanks!

Comment: It means that the "engagement rate" (for exactly what that means you'd have to ask a marketing analyst) is 65% above the average (for information about which average is being used, the data set for which the 'average' has been calculated and the calculation method used you would have to ask the copywriter) engagement rate for some data set. For example if the median engagement rate was 10% then the engagement rate for the Xbox campaign would be 16.5%. This is a typical piece of impressive looking, but ultimately meaningless, advertising speak. If you don't understand it ignore it, I would.

Comment: “ The Engagement Rate of a campaign is the percentage of people who saw a piece of content or ad and engaged with it. For example, if one person interacted one time with an ad after it has had 100 ad impressions, that will give you an ER of 1%.”

Comment: There’s not enough context to pin it down, but it could mean that 67% responded, and that figure is above average.

Comment: Seems to me that the ER for this campaign is 1.67 times the average ER over all previous campaigns.

Comment: Sorry, I read the percenrage as 65 rather than 67. The rest of my comment stands.

Comment: @Lawrence: That's an unlikely intended meaning. If he genuinely wanted to convey that "absolute percentage" sense, any competent writer would have referred to *an above average 67% engagement rate* (or even more explicitly, *an engagement rate of 67%, which is above average*).

Comment: BoldBen's and Jim's comments amount to an answer as to what the most reasonable interpretation is. Theoretically it is possible, but unlikely, that what the advertisers had in mind is that the engagement rate in this case is something like 77%, while it is 10% in an average case. In any event, it is not very likely that analysing this advertisement in a formal answer will illuminate any general feature of English language and usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP’s quote doesn’t amount to a complete sentence. Taking it at face value gets you a measurement that seems too technical for an ad. If the original had a comma after %, or appropriate words surrounding the noun phrase, it could be reporting a more straightforward measurement. My previous comment was just pointing out a less tortured reading of a sentence fragment that might have been incompletely transcribed.

Comment: I'm always deeply suspicious of references to **67%** of *anything*. Makes me think perhaps the figure is reporting on an extremely small sample size, where the writer doesn't want to say *Two of the three cats we asked said they liked our cat food better than dead mice*.